# Simple XML Schema to POJO converter

Tags: xsd, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse to build a Android application. Because I use intensely web service I want to be able to create from XML schema some pojos

For instance:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/VO.Service.Entities" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/VO.Service.Entities" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="TrackCategories">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Category" nillable="true" type="tns:CategoryInfo" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="TrackCategories" nillable="true" type="tns:TrackCategories" />
  <xs:complexType name="CategoryInfo">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CategoryName" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Id" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="CategoryInfo" nillable="true" type="tns:CategoryInfo" />
</xs:schema>
```

I want to be able to create the following class

```
public class CategoryInfo {

 public String CategoryName;
 public Integer Id;

 public String getCategoryName() {
     return CategoryName;
 }


 public void setCategoryName(String value) {
     this.CategoryName =  value;
 }

 public Integer getId() {
     return Id;
 }

 public void setId(Integer value) {
     this.Id = value;
 }

}
```

As simple as that. No binding, no comments just a plain class. I've tried the JABX plugin for Eclipse but the generated classes have a lot of comments and types that I don't need.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used XMLBean by apache - pretty decent classes are generated.

Comment: I tried using XML beans after seeing this answer. XML Beans appears to be quite out of date, doesn't seem to handle Java enum correctly, and the object generated are not POJOs as asked for above.

Answer (score 0):

Castor is a heavier lifting solution if you need moar.